# Cramer's theorem reference request

Tags: probability, reference-request

I'm looking for a proof of Cramer's theorem that states the following:

> Let $X,Y$ two independent random variables such that $X+Y$ is normal distributed, then $X$ and $Y$ are normal distributed.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39413/intuitive-proof-of-cramers-decomposition-theorem

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the original paper: Harald Cramér. "Über eine Eigenschaft der normalen Verteilungsfunktion". Mathematische Zeitschrift, 41 (1): 405–414, 1936.